# lightbox2 where to change opacity

Tags: opacity, lightbox2

lightbox2 is working perfectly on my image gallery. Only mod I made was to get rid of the white image border.

BUT, for the life of me I can't find where to change the opacity of the overlay -- I want it to be opaque.

I do not know js.
Thanks much for help on this. It is the last requirement on a fairly big job.

Comment: hi, You may overwrite `.lightboxOverlay` class css property like `.lightboxOverlay{opacity: 0.5;}`.

Comment: Thanks for answering so quickly -- but that didn't do it. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Poring over lightbox.js I found this line:

new Effect.Appear('overlay', { duration: overlayDuration, from: 0.8, to: 1.0 });   //here was 0.0, to: 0.8

I changed it to what you see now and it works! Line is around 400 - depending on how much you have changed the file.